# I am trying to make a app that outputs your credit score

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that tells you how much your down payment on a house will be if the house was 1 million dollars.

It the user inputs a number that isn't 350 - 850 or puts in a non integer then it will ask the user to put in a valid credit score and will loop that until they do so. Then it will tell the user how much they will have to pay.

I have been struggling on this all day and have no idea what I am doing wrong. If anyone could help?

```
good_credit = range(750, 851)
bad_credit = range(350, 750)
valid_credit_score = range(350, 851)

print("A house is $1,000,000")
question = ("What is your credit score? ")
answer = input(f"{question} ")

for answer in valid_credit_score:
    credit_score = True
else:
    credit_score = False

while credit_score == False:
    print("Please input a valid credit score.")
    answer = input(f"{question} ")
    if answer == range(350, 851):
        credit_score = True
        break
    break

while credit_score == True:
    if answer == good_credit:
        print("Your down payment will be $100,000.")
        break
    elif answer == bad_credit:
        print("Your down payment will be $200,000.")
        break
```

Regardless of any integer I input, it for some reason always makes the credit_score variable false.

Comment: how is an integer going to equal a range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things happening here:

1. You are comparing a value to a range, and for instance, `10 == range(0,20)` will always return False.
2. You are comparing a string to an integer. If you check the type you will see that `answer` is actually a `str`.

```py
type(answer)

Out[1]:
str
```

Therefore you should try:

1. Replace `if int(answer) == good_credit` for `if int(answer) in good_credit`
2. Replace `answer ==` to `int(answer) in`

```py
good_credit = range(750, 851)
bad_credit = range(350, 750)
valid_credit_score = range(350, 851)

print("A house is $1,000,000")
question = ("What is your credit score? ")
answer = input(f"{question} ")

if int(answer) in valid_credit_score:
    credit_score = True
else:
    credit_score = False

while credit_score == False:
    print("Please input a valid credit score.")
    answer = input(f"{question} ")
    if int(answer) in range(350, 851):
        credit_score = True
        break
    break

while credit_score == True:
    if int(answer) in good_credit:
        print("Your down payment will be $100,000.")
        break
    elif int(answer) in bad_credit:
        print("Your down payment will be $200,000.")
        break
```